# How to stop/cancel redux saga when navigating

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am developing an app in react native and I need to stop/cancel redux saga when navigating between screens. How can I accomplish that?

I need this because I want to to avoid the lag when transitioning.
You can see the video to get better my point https://streamable.com/45qsa

My code is below.

MindfulnessScreen.js

```
class MindFulness extends Component {


  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(getMindFulness());
    this.props.dispatch(toggleBottomBar(true));
  }


  render() {
    const { isFetchingData, mindfulnessData, isLoggedIn, userType } = this.props;
    const header = mindfulnessData.header;
    const subHeader = mindfulnessData.subheader;
    const imageBanner = FILES_URL + mindfulnessData.image_banner;
    const mindFulnessDatas = mindfulnessData.children;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#1F1F20' }}>
        {isFetchingData && <LoadingIndicator />}
        {/* <BottomBar screen={'MindFulness'} navigation={this.props.navigation} /> */}
        <ScrollView style={{ flexGrow: 1, marginBottom: 35 }}>
          {!isFetchingData && <FastImage
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: 137,
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
            resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
            source={{ uri: imageBanner }}
          >
            <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', paddingLeft: 30, paddingRight: 30 }}>
              <Text style={{
                textAlign: 'center',
                fontSize: 20,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                fontFamily: Theme.FONT_BOLD
              }}>{header}</Text>
              <Text style={{
                textAlign: 'center',
                fontSize: 14,
                paddingTop: 8,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                fontFamily: Theme.FONT_MEDIUM
              }}>{subHeader}</Text>
            </View>
          </FastImage>}

          {this.renderData(mindFulnessDatas)}

          {!isFetchingData && isLoggedIn && userType == 0 && <View style={{
            width: width,
            height: 200,
            marginBottom: 30,
            borderRadius: 12,
            shadowRadius: 16,
            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 8 },
            shadowColor: "black",
            shadowOpacity: 0.47,
            elevation: 2
          }}
          >
            <FastImage style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} source={unlockActivitiesBannerImage}>
              <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text style={{
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: '#FFFFFF',
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: 40,
                  fontFamily: Theme.FONT_BOLD
                }}>{'All Synesthesia Meditations \n 7 days for free'}</Text>

                <CustomButton
                  disabled={false}
                  style={{
                    height: 50,
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    marginTop: 45,
                    width: 230,
                    borderRadius: 45,
                    backgroundColor: '#25B999',
                    opacity: 1
                  }}
                  title="Start free trial"
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.props.dispatch(setMenuItem('7 days for free'))
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Pricing')
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </FastImage>
          </View>}


        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isFetchingData: state.mindfulnessReducer.isFetchingData,
    mindfulnessData: state.mindfulnessReducer.mindfulnessData
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MindFulness);
```

AwarenessScreen is similar to MindfulnessScreen.js

MindFulnessAction.js

```
import { ActionTypes } from '../constants/constants'

export function getMindFulness() {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.GET_MINDFULNESS,
    payload: {}
  }
}
```

mindulnessReducer.js

```
import { ActionTypes } from '../constants/constants'

const initialState = {
  error: false,
  isFetchingData: false,
  mindfulnessData: [],
};

export const mindfulnessReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.GET_MINDFULNESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetchingData: true
      }
    case ActionTypes.GET_MINDFULNESS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetchingData: false,
        mindfulnessData: action.payload.node
      }
    case ActionTypes.GET_MINDFULNESS_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: true,
        isFetchingData: false
      }
    default:
      return state
  }

}
```

api.js

```
let commonHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

export const getMindFulness = (token) => fetch(`${baseUrl}node/337?token=${token}`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    ...commonHeaders,
  },
}).then(response => response.json());
```

mindFulnessSaga.js

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

import { put, call, select } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { ActionTypes } from '../constants/constants'
import { getMindFulness, getMindFulnessAnonymous } from '../api/api'

export const getMindfulnessData = (state) => state.mindfulnessReducer.mindfulnessData;

const MindFulnessSaga = function* (action) {
  const token = yield AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
  const mindfulnessData = yield select(getMindfulnessData);

  // if (mindfulnessData.length == 0) {
  if (token !== null) {
    const dataObject = yield call(getMindFulness, token);
    if (dataObject.status.success) {
      yield put({
        type: ActionTypes.GET_MINDFULNESS_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
          ...dataObject
        }
      })
    }
    else {
      yield put({
        type: ActionTypes.GET_MINDFULNESS_FAIL
      })
    }
  }
  else {
    const dataObject = yield call(getMindFulnessAnonymous);
    yield put({
      type: ActionTypes.GET_MINDFULNESS_SUCCESS,
      payload: {
        ...dataObject
      }
    })
  }
  // }
}

export default MindFulnessSaga
```

rootSaga.js

```
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { ActionTypes } from '../constants/constants'
import MindFulnessSaga from './MindFulnessSaga'
import BeingAwareSaga from './BeingAwareSaga'


const rootSaga = function* () {
  yield takeLatest(ActionTypes.GET_MINDFULNESS, MindFulnessSaga)
  yield takeLatest(ActionTypes.GET_BEINGAWARE, BeingAwareSaga)
}

export default rootSaga
```

Any recommendations?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

My original answer (I left it below) wasn't correct. I made a mistake while talking about the `takeLatest` effect because, as [the docs say](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takelatestpattern-saga-args)

> Spawns a saga on each action dispatched to the Store that matches a pattern. **And automatically cancels** any previous saga task started previously if it's still running.

So the previous `MindFulnessSaga`/`BeingAwareSaga` are automatically canceled by the `takeLatest` effect. That doesn't mean that the AJAX calls are canceled too if you want to cancel the previous AJAX calls you need to manage the cancellation your own.

You can manage a saga cancellation by putting all its code in a try/finally and manage it in the `finally` block

```
import { cancelled } from 'redux-saga/effects'
function* MindFulnessSaga() {
  try {
    // ... your code
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled())
      // the saga has been cancelled, cancel the AJAX request too
  }
}
```

That said: the lag on navigation could be related to the fact that you don't cache the AJAX response (but you did it at the beginning since you have commented the `// if (mindfulnessData.length == 0) {` block).

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

You need to:

- replace the `takeLatest` with a custom infinite loop ([docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeeverypattern-saga-args))
- `fork` ([docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/ForkModel.html)) the different sagas so you can `cancel` ([docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html)) them later
- `cancel` the forked sagas when the user navigates to another screen

Look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256847/how-to-cancel-saga-task-when-specific-action-is-dispatched/55352222#55352222) for a step-by-step explanation.

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I integrated fork and cancel but they didn't do the trick. I suspect that maybe it is a redux thing eventually.

Comment: Could you share it on codesandbox? Or is it long to be converted to a standard react site?

Comment: It's a time consuming to do that but probably I'll give it a try with a minimalistic version of it.

Comment: One more question: have you tried to cache the response uncommenting your length check?

Comment: @thodwris? Have you made some more tries?

Comment: Thank you for asking. Actually I reached to the conclusion that my redux is responsible for this delay. Maybe the logic behind that and the way I'm using it is not the appropriate.